# Uploading video to http server from android app

Tags: android, http

I am trying to upload a video file from android device to http server. And I used multipart file upload. The code, when used with audio file is working correctly. But when I try to upload a video file I am getting HttpHostConnectException. I added all the necessary permissions in the app.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest=new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8090/WebAppTest/rest/file/upload?name=five.mp4");

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new  MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            FileBody fb = new FileBody(filename, "video/3gpp");
            FormBodyPart bodyPart = new FormBodyPart("file",fb);
                reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse  response=httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski is there anything wrong with the question?

Comment: it was. code block formatting. you can always see the diff of edit by clicking on "edited ...."

Comment: But the previous is also in readable format right?

Answer (score 1):

public class BigFileUpload
{

```
public static String TAG = "filevideoupload";
private static final char PARAMETER_DELIMITER = '&';
private static final char PARAMETER_EQUALS_CHAR = '=';

public String sendFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl, String videoName)
{
    String response = "error";
    String postParameters;
    Log.e(TAG, filename);
    Log.e(TAG, targetUrl);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = filename;
    String urlServer = targetUrl;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    // DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        String connstr = null;
        connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + videoName + "\"" + lineEnd;
        Log.i(TAG, "connstr->" + connstr);

        outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Log.e(TAG, "bytesAvailable " + bytesAvailable + "");
        try
        {
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "outofmemoryerror";

                    Log.e(TAG, "115  OOM ");
                    return response;
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "bytesAvailable error in try  124" + bytesAvailable + "");

            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "error";
            return response;
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        Log.e(TAG, "112 --> end of wrte");

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "server response code " + serverResponseCode);
        Log.i(TAG, "server response msg " + connection.getResponseMessage());

        if (serverResponseCode == 200)
        {
            response = "true";
        }
        InputStream is;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200)
        {
            is = connection.getErrorStream();
        }
        else
        {
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        }
        // s.useDelimiter("\\Z");

        Log.i(TAG, "server response content " + getStringFromInputStream(is));

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception handling
        response = "error";
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage() + "");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Time for uplaod " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 + " sekund:)");
    return response;
}

private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is)
{

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try
    {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

}

Use this class  for file upload. I use it for video uploading.

it does work

Comment: Please note that you need to provide right server side code to.

Comment: I tried executing the code and ended up with timedout exception

Comment: Is the file to big? and takes to long time to upload to the server?

Comment: No.. I buffered the content of the file and uploading the chunks, and each chunk size is not too big

Comment: Well for sure its server problem.